# How can I create a view like background view of UIActionSheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to have an `UIActionSheet` with custom `UIAlertAction` but seem like custom `UIAlertAction` is not legal.

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

So I'm trying to create a view which look exactly like `UIActionSheet`. By using `Debug View Hierarchy`, I can know how Apple applies hierarchy, constraint, color for `UIActionSheet` to do exactly which they did.

[image]

I can create everything except `UIActionSheet`'s background. It's a view which contains a non-transparent view and an `UIVisualEffectView`.

The `UIVisualEffectView` overlap non-transparent view but somehow `UIVisualEffectView` still works.

[image]

How can `UIVisualEffectView` still work when there is a non-transparent below it? If it's possible, how can I make something like this?

Note: Background of `UIActionSheet` is not only an `UIVisualEffectView`. Please don't give an answer like this.

Comment: what you want to do ?i am little bit confuse.

Comment: I want an `UIView` with blur effect exactly like effect of action sheet's background.

Comment: ok got it. i think you should do that with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view below the `UIVisualEffectView` (the one with the red arrow in the question) contains a layer which has a CAFilter "overlayBlendMode" (private class) set as compositing filter. It's applied over the layer behind it. In the screenshot below I changed the background colour of the _UIDimmingKnockoutBackdropView to green and the filter is applied over that.

[image]

**Private method**

To create the same effect, you need to put a white opaque view below the `UIVisualEffectView` and apply a CAFilter to it:

```
CAFilter *filter = [CAFilter filterWithName:@"overlayBlendMode"];
[[contentView layer] setCompositingFilter:filter];
```

Since CAFilter is private, we need a header for it:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CAFilter : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying> {
    void * _attr;
    void * _cache;
    unsigned int  _flags;
    NSString * _name;
    unsigned int  _type;
}

@property BOOL cachesInputImage;
@property (getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (readonly) NSString *type;

// Image: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore

+ (void)CAMLParserStartElement:(id)arg1;
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(id)arg1;
+ (id)filterTypes;
+ (id)filterWithName:(id)arg1;
+ (id)filterWithType:(id)arg1;

- (void)CAMLParser:(id)arg1 setValue:(id)arg2 forKey:(id)arg3;
- (id)CAMLTypeForKey:(id)arg1;
- (struct Object { int (**x1)(); struct Atomic { struct { int x_1_2_1; } x_2_1_1; } x2; }*)CA_copyRenderValue;
- (BOOL)cachesInputImage;
- (id)copyWithZone:(struct _NSZone { }*)arg1;
- (void)dealloc;
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (void)encodeWithCAMLWriter:(id)arg1;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithName:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithType:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)isEnabled;
- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(struct _NSZone { }*)arg1;
- (id)name;
- (void)setCachesInputImage:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setDefaults;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setName:(id)arg1;
- (void)setValue:(id)arg1 forKey:(id)arg2;
- (id)type;
- (id)valueForKey:(id)arg1;

// Image: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosUICore.framework/PhotosUICore

+ (id)px_filterWithPXCompositingFilterType:(int)arg1;

@end
```

The result:
[image]

The view I've created prints the same compositing filter as Apple used:
[image]

**Workaround**

As a workaround you can create an image of the view on the background and a image of the white view and apply the overlay blend mode with that. This results in a comparable result as using the private class.

Example:

```
    UIImage *image = [self imageForView:contentView];
    UIView *superview = [contentView superview];

    [contentView setHidden:YES];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self imageForView:superview];
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([backgroundImage CGImage], [contentView frame]);
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    [contentView setHidden:NO];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIOverlayBlendMode"];
    [filter setValue:[backgroundImage CIImage] forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:[image CIImage] forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[filter outputImage]]]];
}

- (UIImage *)imageForView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([view bounds].size, [view isOpaque], 1.0);
    [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you know the view which you are talking about have white color and non-transparent background? Try to create something like this and you will know it's possible or not.

Comment: When you give a `CIFilter` for `compositingFilter` property, you will get `compositingFilter = <CIOverlayBlendMode: inputImage=nil inputBackgroundImage=nil>` instead of `compositingFilter = overlayBlendMode`

Comment: One more, you should edit previous answer instead of creating new answer.

Comment: Since all reactions are not based on my new answer and the old answer might be usefull to other people I created a new answer. A CIFilter is not the same as a CAFilter used by Apple internally, that's why the description printed differs (I also tried to replicate it). So it's impossible to be completely sure how Apple creates the background of the view/layer in the UIAlertController. We only can guess how to replicate it. (to get the class of the compositingFilter: [[[view layer] compositingFilter] class])

Comment: Please focus on my question: How can `UIVisualEffectView` still work when there is a non-transparent below it? If it's possible, how can I make something like this? **If you know the answer, give me you answer. Don't say it's impossible or something like this. If not, don't give any answer. I don't want give you down vote**

Comment: I don't believe in impossible, so I won't answer that :-) I am able to replicate Apples way to apply the filter to it, but to do that I needed to add a private header to my project. I've added it to the answer. It seems compositing filters aren't support on iOS 'This property is not supported on layers in iOS.'. So I will be looking into a way to do it with a workaround, but still get the same effect.

Comment: I have checked your new answer. It works but it's an illegal solution. If I can use an illegal solution, I will custom ActionSheet directly instead of using your answer ;).

Comment: However, it satisfies my curiosity ;). Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @MaartenFoukhar is the `contentView` in your workaround example the contentView of the `UIVisualEffectView`? I'm trying to replicate what you've done but I'm just a little confused where this code is executing from, the function is cut off at the top.

Comment: @ShawnThroop The content view is a white view behind the top UIVisualEffectView, it has the same size. So in the third screenshot (from top to bottom): UIWindow -> KSViewController -> UIView (contentView) -> UIVisualEffectView -> UIVisualEffectView. It seems though Apple changed some things, which make it that you can't directly get a CIImage from a UIImage. So an alternative might be CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];.

Comment: @MaartenFoukhar thanks for the clarification, I should have looked closer at the screenshot. I’m thinking a solution similar to Apple’s private implementation won’t work because I would be displaying the interface (`contentView.superview`) over a dynamic interface instead of a static image. I’ll use your advice and try some things, UIView does have quick snapshot capabilities (`snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`

Answer (score 1):

Please check my storyboard views set up and result. 
I used actual apple's action sheet with same image to control the result.

**Storyboard set up**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

**Original apple's action sheet**
[image]

And one of approaches to implement custom action sheet 
You can check apple's docs for dynamic stack view [Dynamically Changing the Stack View’s Content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

Comment: Sorry but I can't get the point of your question. Can you explain it more detail?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce effect you needed for action sheet. which part is not clear? I will add more details. Try to arrange views in same way I did in my storyboard to check wether this effect works for you

Comment: Now I got it but you should check the effect carefully. Seem like they are the same but they aren't. You can use color picker to check color on a same point to compare your custom view and action sheet background.

Comment: Images positioned slightly different that's why color picker could provide different results. Also maybe they have different alpha (not 0.1) I think it's one of the most close options. Why you need exact pixel to pixel style ?

Comment: You can move position of your view to make it be same. For your why question, it's just to satisfy my curiosity, how Apple can do it ;)

Comment: *Also maybe they have different alpha (not 0.1)*. I tried but it's not the solution.

Comment: I once spent a fortune of time to implement apples iMessage animation. Which seems possible with UIKIt dynamics. But it was too slow. Later I found thread on forum saying that apple is using some private API for that. You should consider that they can use something internall for that effect.

Comment: which means you should use some of your workarounds to reach same exact effect

Comment: Actually, I have created an `UIViewController` which works exactly like ActionSheet except its background effect. I used alpha as you said above. At least, thank for your effort :D

Comment: No problem :) was interesting task to tackle with